# Preference with custom Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm currently building `PreferenceScreen` in an xml file. One of its child elements, more precisely `Preference` element, has a property called [android:setFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setFragment(java.lang.String)) with the following description:

> Sets the class name of a fragment to be shown when this Preference is clicked.

So I added my custom fragment in the preference xml file:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:title = "test"
        android:fragment="com.test.bla.SomeTestFragment"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is how I defined my custom fragment (which actually extends `DialogFragment`):

```
public class SomeTestFragment extends DialogFragment 
{
    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = SomeTestFragment.class.getName();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
        dialog.setTitle("Delete User");

        FragmentDeleteUserBinding binding = FragmentDeleteUserBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));
        binding.setFragment(this);

        dialog.setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onClickDeleteCredential()
    {
       DeleteCredentialFragment.deleteCredential(getChildFragmentManager());
    }


    public void onClickClose()
    {
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

But when I click on that preference nothing happens, custom fragment isn't showing. Do I miss something here?

Someone will probably ask why I force my custom `DialogFragment`. It is just because I have access to `getChildFragmentManager` method and I can't achieve the same thing if my custom fragment would extend from `DialogPreference`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not explicit, but I think the fragment has to be a PreferenceFragment.

> With the android:fragment attribute, each header declares an instance
>   of PreferenceFragment that should open when the user selects the
>   header.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

What you can do, though, is in your PreferenceActivity or main PreferenceFragment, set an onClickListener on that preference and then use FragmentManager to show the fragment after adding it to the backstack:

```
class SettingsFragment: PreferenceFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            // Set click listener for directory picker
            findPreference("addKeyboard").setOnPreferenceClickListener( {
                preference ->

                try {
                    // Display the fragment as the main content.
                      fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(android.R.id.content, ManageKeyboardsFragment())
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit()
                    true

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    displayError("could not open managekeyboards fragment", e)
                    true
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the string you provide in the `fragment` attribtue is just a message to send to your parent activity. Your parent activity is responsible for instantiating the right `Fragment`, and performing the ceremony to render it.

The [platform docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings) seem to indicate as such:

> When a user taps a Preference with an associated Fragment, the interface method PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback.onPreferenceStartFragment() is called

The arguments of `onPreferenceStartFragment` appear to be the clicked-on Preference and the PreferenceFragmentCompat which hosts it.

That page hosts a code example where the implementation of `onPreferenceStartFragment` passes the return value `pref.getFragment()` in to `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentFactory().instantiate`.

At this point, I'm using Xamarin and for whatever reason `getFragmentFactory` doesn't have an equivalent API. But the point is, sadly, the `fragment` attribute isn't magic; your `Activity` has to do the heavy lifting.

Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54663247/2821583) where I wrote out a more complete working example, but in C# / Xamarin.