# How to use PreferenceFragmentCompat in the preference header

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to learn ways to build preference pages in the Xamarin Android application.
I found a lot of examples with PreferenceFragment but it was marked as deprecated and it is difficult for me to rewrite them on the current stage.

I've created activity to represent headers. I added IntentFilter so I can access this activity from apps list in the settings menu. Also it has internal class to group some preferences together:

```
namespace droid.examples.Preferences
{
    [Activity(Label = "Settings activity", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", Name = "droid.examples.Preferences.SettingsActivity")]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" })]
    public class SettingsActivity : PreferenceActivity
    {
        public override void OnBuildHeaders(IList<Header> target)
        {
            base.OnBuildHeaders(target);
            LoadHeadersFromResource(Resource.Xml.preference_headers, target);
        }

        public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat
        {
            public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
            {
                // Load the Preferences from the XML file
                SetPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.app_preferences, rootKey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app_preferences.xml which I can't open by selecting "Prefs 1" header from preference_headers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="Category">
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="checkbox_preference"
            android:title="Developer mode"
            android:summary="Allow user to see detailed messages" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have preference_headers.xml. It opens when I click on gear wheel near application name. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <header android:fragment="droid.examples.Preferences.SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment"
          android:title="Prefs 1"
          android:summary="An example of some preferences." />
</preference-headers>
```

My package name: droid.examples

I think that one problem related to the android:fragment attribute value.
What is the rules to build that value?

I suppose that it must start from 'package name'. Should it contain namespace between class name and package name?

What does $ mean in the attribute value? Is it used to mark internal class? I saw in the several places next code:

`android:fragment="com.example.android.apis.preference.PreferenceWithHeaders$Prefs1Fragment"`

I hope you can help me find where I made a mistakes.

[Source code from GitHub](https://github.com/Shumigaj/XamarinExamples/tree/59d6af15350a9354e59f716e648bd54d12a5f889)

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test it ?

Comment: Good point @AbbyWang. I've added link to GitHub repository and updated code samples in the question so that everything matches

Comment: I can't find a good reference, but the `$` is what the JVM uses to delimit inner class names. So for `class A { class B {} }` in *java code* you'd refer to `A.B`, but *at runtime in the JVM* `A.B.class.getName()` returns `"A$B"`. In C# the equivalent is `+`.

Answer (score 1):

I spend a lot of time to investigate that issue and I want to make a summary.

We have to override IsValidFragment method in the SettingsActivity:

```
protected override bool IsValidFragment(string fragmentName)
{
    return fragmentName == "droid.examples.preferences.SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment";
}
```

My SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity. Thanks to @Jeremy advice about implementation of IOnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback I find out that base class already extends it.

```
public abstract class PreferenceActivity ...
{
    ...
    public virtual bool OnPreferenceStartFragment(PreferenceFragment caller, Preference pref);
    ...
}
```

So, I probably need to use PreferenceFragment instead of PreferenceFragmentCompat to make code consistent:

```
public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.app_preferences_for_header);
    }
}
```

Also we have to add Register attribute to our fragment:

```
[Register("droid.examples.preferences.SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment")]
public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragment
{
}
```

Finally I updated preference_headers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <header android:fragment="droid.examples.preferences.SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment"
          android:title="Prefs 1"
          android:summary="An example of some preferences." />
</preference-headers>
```

android:fragment attribute value can contains '$' but '+' won't work because Register doesn't support it and we will get compilation error.

Thanks everyone who tried to help me

Comment: I *think* the best-practice advice is not to use PreferenceActivity, but the Android API deprecation scene is such a mess I'd suggest sticking with it if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the string you provide is just a message to send to your parent activity. Your parent activity is responsible for instantiating the right `Fragment`, and performing the ceremony to render it.

The [platform docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings) seem to indicate as such:

> When a user taps a Preference with an associated Fragment, the interface method PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback.onPreferenceStartFragment() is called

At time of writing, there's a code snippet on that page, which I've translated for my own project more-or-less as follows:

```
// This has to go in the activity which hosts the PreferenceFragment
// which owns the Preference that has the `android:fragment` attribute.

using Android.Support.V7.Preferences;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
partial class MyActivity :
   PreferenceFragmentCompat.IOnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback
{

   Fragment GetFragmentForPrefString(string prefFragment)
   {
      // you implement this
   }
   const int fragmentContainerId = Resource.Id.whatever;

   public bool OnPreferenceStartFragment(
      PreferenceFragmentCompat caller, Preference pref)
   {
      string prefString = pref.Fragment;
      var transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
      transaction.Replace(fragmentContainerId,
         GetFragmentForPrefString(prefString));

      // you'll probably also want to add it to the back stack,
      // but it's not strictly necessary I guess.

      transaction.Commit();
      return true;
   }
}
```

Their sample involves the Java API method `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentFactory()` which doesn't appear to be part of the V28 Xamarin support NuGet packages. But honestly I'm not sure why that level of indirection is necessary; I'd suggest you simply implement something like

```
switch (prefFragmentName)
{
   case "Fragment 1":
      return new Fragment1();
// etc
```